# Is there a program for converting ARM assembly to MIPS assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm, mips

I have found a few different programs for converting ARM binaries to MIPS binaries or converting ARM to MIPS at run-time, but I am looking for something that will convert ARM assembly code to MIPS (.S text files, so that I can debug and optimize the resulting code).  Are there any programs out there that can do this (or a series of tools that can accomplish this)?  I've found some basic guides on ARM to MIPS translation strategies, but figure the job will be easier if I there is a tool that can do the heavy lifting and then fine-tune the results.

Comment: Convert the binaries and then disassemble?

Comment: Converting assembly from one architecture to another often results in code that is not very good. There are many, tiny details in an instrution set, like what ops will set what status flags. How closely will you have to simulate that? At what cost? There *is* a reason people use languages like C.

Comment: Thanks, BlackBear, I had considered that, but it wouldn't be as good as converting the code (losing things like higher-level stuff, comments, etc).  It may be the only option though if there isn't a tool that works at the code level.

Comment: Thanks, Bo Persson, I do understand that converting from one architecture to another often results in code that isn't very good, which is one of the reasons I don't want to do it at the binary level (so I can alter the results so they work better).  This is for a dynarec which has to be written in assembly to be useable (C is not an option in this case).